# How to ingest data from Kafka into Siddhi?

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I went through this tutorial to set up a Kafka Event Receiver: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Kafka+Event+Receiver

I did all the prerequisites described in the link above and set up an event receiver to ingest data from Kafka on my local machine and map it to a particular stream.

**Question:**

How do I start ingesting the data from Kafka and start pushing it to the event receiver I created above? Do I have to start some program in Siddhi to start the ingestion from Kafka or something? It is not mentioned clearly in the link on how to start ingesting from Kafka into the event receiver.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Sample+0018+-+Receiving+JSON+Events+via+Kafka+Transport) on how to publish to the wso2cep with a Kafka event receiver. Please let me know if there is any confusions.

Best Regards,
Ramindu